# Prevent users from preventing my website ADs from being displayed?

Tags: advertising, adblock

It may not be 100% of the users but even a localized amount of users that make use of ads blocking features will reduce your incoming.

I do care about my users as well as I do care about receiving some incoming for my hard work.

Currently I keep an watch on the ADs being displayed and remove the ones that have eye-hurting type of either images or text, ADs that are non-related to my content and I don't exagerate on ADs, i have 2 ads on a rather big content website and am planning to add an Amazon Store thing later.

Now I would like to know:

1. What type of ADs do you usually remove from users view ?
2. Are there ways to prevent this sort of blocking ?
3. What kinda of work arounds you usually do to prevent it ?

   ***The difference between question 2 and 3 is that question 2 is related to legitmate ways to prevent this while question 3 is regarding any way to work around it.***
4. What ADs Format do you use the most, what type (image, flash, text) and how does it influence on the above ?

Comment: If they choose to block ads then that is there own business.  It is REALLY bad form on your part to try and prevent users from controlling what happens in their own browsers.

Comment: No, not really. It is our problems as well wether we solve it with a radical way or a different way is also our problem. Like the advices that were given to me there inst only 1 way to solve the issue. For instance i can try to mail my user telling them about what supports me and my website or make a public post announcement about it... Here i am just looking at the possibilities and alternatives i can pick up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blocking people from blocking ads is virtually impossible, as at the end of the day the user has full control over their browser. If I want to disable 99.999% of all ads on the internet today, I would

- Disable Images
- Disable Javascript
- Disable iFrames

from my Firefox and although the internet would look pretty crappy and broken, I 99.999% of all ads would be gone.

The way most ad blockers work is they search image, javascript and iFrame URLs for known keywords, and then generic keywords (e.g. 'adsense' 'doubleclick' and 'ad', etc).

To get around this your best bet would be to serve the ads in-house by rendering the insertion code server-side and avoiding all keywords.

For example, instead of including:

`<script src="myadscript.js">` which then loads an iFrame which then loads a JPG (as a lot of ad clients do), you would need to serve up:

`<img src="/somethingthatsnotanad/bagdgf.jpg" />` - now `bagdgf.jpg` might very well a PHP script that does the ad fetching and whatnot for you, or it could be a link to a real ad, but that's going to be the only way to defeat a lot of ad blockers, as they'll have a hard time differentiating between that image and an ad image.

-- Addendum --

You'll also most likely need to mask the affiliate URL you're linking to as well, because ad blockers will have a good method of matching these. If your `<href>` is linking directly to the affiliate, it will probably still get caught. You'll need to also mask this with a server-side redirect, so your `href` might point to `/jsdaf.php?id=$adid` and from there do a `301 Redirect`

Comment: @Farseeker, I am very appreciated by your answer and that was what I was also thinking about this, but since I am new as being a webmaster I wanted to make sure. So I guess that also means I wouldnt being able to use Adsense aswell or is there a PHP ADS Admin that can actually render adsense as if it was an image or so ?

Comment: Adsense works through javascript directly talking between the client and the adsense network. That's why it's so easy to block. If you were to cache a local copy of it, it would be personalized to your visit not theirs. It would also not be able to be tracked by adsense so they would never know how many links you sent them that were valid to pay you for.

Comment: @Prix - what XOPJ said is correct

Comment: @XOPJ nice insight :) so is there any ADs that will either allow me to pump in the image or mask it to prevent blocking ?

Comment: @Prix: Only ads that you sell directly yourself, since you can control the URLs you use for images etc.

Comment: You would need to install/build/host something on your site that allows you to supply the data and record the metrics. Most people just offer a simple plan of "I'll host your image Ad for a month for $xx". It's easier to maintain if you're not using some full blown software or looking to invest in the time required to maintain accounts for your advertisers. There are some out of the box AD packages but without some serious demand to display Ad's on your site you'll be better off using adsense and just hoping users aren't blocking them. You can always mix both kinds of Ads.

Comment: Note that ad blockers can also block based on the dimensions of the image/iframe. Ad blockers know that, for instance, 468 x 60 is a standard banner size, and that image/iframe will be blocked, even if you serve it from your host.

Answer (score 2):

There's simply no point in trying to prevent your visitors from blocking your ads. They will always find a way to do it. Before you spend a huge amount of time trying to prevent ad blocking, you should ask yourself this question:

Are the types of people that block ads also the type of people that click ads?

The point is you can try to prevent people from blocking your ads, but if someone is smart enough to use an ad blocker, then they're also smart enough to avoid clicking on ads.